# Strange Contact status

Tags: contacts, 3.2-honeycomb

In my contacts there is a text area between the photo and the emails. How do I edit it? Something put something inappropriate there and I would like to get rid of it.

Thanks

Model: Vizio 
Android Version: 3.2.1 HTK55

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click it for larger variant)</sup>

The area in the blue oval.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? :)

Comment: This seems to be the area reserved for display any status message from social network if connected. Are you connected to fb, twitter etc?

Comment: If I remember a while back my twitter account has some junk on it but since then I've changed it and updated it. Any ideas of how to change this?

Comment: @Izzy thanks for changing the link I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: You're welcome, Aaron -- that's what "brothers" are for :)